# Removing duplicate results from unionall in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I am running a union of `select` and `match` queries, whose results for the purpose of this question is equivalent to this: (try with the demo database)

```
select expand(unionall(
  (select from castles limit 6),
  (select from castles limit 3)
))
```

The problem is that these queries come out with some duplicate results, and I wish to remove duplicates.

From reading docs, I found that one can wrap it with `select distinct @this` which seems to work, but I imagine there must be a cleaner way.

The following solves my problem, but is there a simpler way?

```
select expand(*) from (select distinct(@this) from (
  select expand(unionall(
    (select from castles limit 6),
    (select from castles limit 3)
))))
```

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Why did you need to do limit 6 and then limit 3? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asSet()` seems to be the answer. It can be used on result data, and will remove duplicates.

https://orientdb.com/docs/last/sql/SQL-Methods.html#asset

Full query:

```
select expand(unionall(
    (select from castles limit 6),
    (select from castles limit 3)
).asSet())
```